# Set alpha on top to 0 percent and on bottom to 70 percent - Android - Kotlin

Tags: android, css, kotlin, gradient, alpha

So I have some imageviews with a title which is barely visible if the image uploaded is for example white on the bottom because of the white title text. Now our designer told me to make a gradient with 0 percent at the top and 70 percent on the bottom (alpha). Now with colors and stuff I already figured it out but I just can not seem to find a way to do it with alpha.
Is there anyone who can help me out here? 
I've been searching stackoverflow for quite some time but none of the topics resolved my issue so far.

So far I have tried the following:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#80000000"
    android:startColor="@null"
    android:type="linear"/>
```

but that didn't turn out to be correct and the fact that my designer told me to do it like I am asking in the question above makes me limited in my options.

Any help would strongly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since android uses `#SRGB` color space, 70% alpha is approx. `B3`.
Try this:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#B3000000"
    android:startColor="#00000000"
    android:type="linear"/>
```

Comment: @frankhardenberg, happy to help!